# High performance simple Java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Part of the code I'm working on uses a bunch of regular expressions to search for some simple string patterns (e.g., patterns like "foo[0-9]{3,4} bar"). Currently, we use statically-compiled Java Patterns and then call `Pattern#matcher` to check whether a string has contains a match to the pattern (I don't need the match, just a boolean indicating whether there is a match). This is causing a noticeable amount of memory allocation that is affecting performance.

Is there a better option for Java regex matching that is faster or at least doesn't allocate memory every time it searches a string for a pattern?

Comment: what about http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String) this will return boolean

Comment: @c0mrade <String>.matches(<pattern>) does the same as Pattern.matches(<pattern>,<string>) which does the same thing as Pattern.compile(<pattern>).matcher(<string>).matches()

Comment: @Jared correct, but he said he was using pattern/matcher not string matches

Comment: @c0mrade the big difference is that he said he is using statically compiled Patterns, using <String>.matches will compile the same pattern every time it is called, taking more time and memory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `matcher.reset("newinputtext")` method to avoid creating new matchers each time you are calling Pattern.matcher.

Comment: That should improve speed to some degree.. see my [admittedly weak] test here: http://pastie.org/2570213

Comment: This is good, but note that the Matcher class is not thread-safe. In a threaded environment, initialize a Matcher for each thread or just use a pre-compiled static Pattern (Pattern class is thread-safe but that gives you the same memory allocation issue you started with).

Answer (score 4):

If you expect less than 50% of lines matching your regex, you can first try to test for some subsequence via `String.indexOf()` which is about 3 to 20 times faster for simple sequence compared to regex matcher:

```
if (line.indexOf("foo")>-1) && pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
    ...
```

If you add to your code such heuristics, remember to always well document them, and verify using profiler that code is indeed faster compared to simple code.

Comment: And also add test ensuring that the optimized version does the same or the plain regex. This comes handy if someone changes the regex and forgets about the rest.

Comment: Good hint - this also works for contains, and the match doesn't have to be perfect - it just needs to be enough to reduce the number of things going to the pattern matcher by at least 50%

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid creating a new Matcher for each Pattern, use the [`usePattern()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#usePattern%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) method, like so:

```
Pattern[] pats = {
  Pattern.compile("123"),
  Pattern.compile("abc"),
  Pattern.compile("foo")
};
String s = "123 abc";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("dummy").matcher(s);
for (Pattern p : pats)
{
  System.out.printf("%s : %b%n", p.pattern(), m.reset().usePattern(p).find());
}
```

**[see the demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/g1Y7x)**

You have to use matcher's `reset()` method too, or `find()` will only search from the point where the previous match ended (assuming the match was successful).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Pattern.matches()` static method which would just return the boolean.  That wouldn't return a `Matcher` object so it could help with the memory allocation issues.

That being said the regex pattern would not be precompiled so it would be a performance vs resources thing at the point.

Comment: `Pattern#matches` creates a Matcher object inside that method.

Comment: @jonderry: Very good point +1. It actually creates both, Pattern by compiling a regex and creates Mather for given input.