# Pooling issue: Item borrowed more than once

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a utility method (= a `static` one) that I call a lot, which uses a `java.util.regex.Matcher`. As the regex passed is reused a lot, I try not to compile it every time, so I keep it in a `Map` where the key is the regex, and the value is a `List` of `Matcher` objects (so that each thread gets it own `Matcher` instance).

How is it that the following code snippet manages to return the same `Matcher` twice... sometimes?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyTest {

    private static final Map<String, Queue<Matcher>> matchers = new HashMap<String, Queue<Matcher>>();
    private static Set<Integer> duplicateHunter = new HashSet<Integer>();

    private static Matcher getMatcher(String regexp, String value) {
        Queue<Matcher> matcherQueue = matchers.get(regexp);

        if (matcherQueue == null) {
            synchronized (matchers) {
                matcherQueue = matchers.get(regexp);

                if (matcherQueue == null) {
                    // Create a new thread-safe Queue and a new Matcher
                    matcherQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Matcher>();
                    matchers.put(regexp, matcherQueue);
                } // Else: another thread already did what needed to be done
            }
        }

        // Try to retrieve a Matcher
        Matcher matcher = matcherQueue.poll();

        if (matcher == null) {
            // No matchers available, create one
            // No lock needed, as it's not a drama to have a few more matchers in the queue
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
            matcherQueue.offer(matcher);
        } else {
            // reset the matcher
            matcher.reset(value);
        }

//        boolean notADuplicate = duplicateHunter.add(matcher.hashCode());
//        if(!notADuplicate) {
//            throw new RuntimeException("DUPLICATE!!!");
//        }

        return matcher;
    }

    private static void returnMatcher(String regex, Matcher matcher) {
        Queue<Matcher> matcherQueue = matchers.get(regex);
        //duplicateHunter.remove(matcher.hashCode());
        matcherQueue.offer(matcher);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
                        String regex = ".*";
                        Matcher matcher = null;
                        try {
                            matcher = getMatcher(regex, "toto" + i);
                            if (matcher.matches()) {
                                // matches
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (matcher != null) {
                                returnMatcher(regex, matcher);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            });

            thread.start();
        }

    }
}
```

You'll get a "`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`: String index out of range". Enable the `duplicateHunter` code and you'll see that a `Matcher` is indeed returned twice sometimes.

(The `static` utility method isn't shown, the `main` method was made to show you the problem)

Comment: Why are you caching Matchers instead of Patterns? I'd have thought the latter approach would be far simpler, as Pattern is immutable thread-safe.

Comment: Why not just use commons-pool?

Comment: @Jon: Another question's reply (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505160/high-performance-simple-java-regular-expressions) told me that reusing Matchers give you "some" performance boost. The micro-bench linked there (http://pastie.org/2570213) showed this little performance boost. I know that microbenches are bad in Java, but I was still convinced somehow.

Comment: @AndrewBourgeois: Which would you rather have: complicated, buggy code which might have *some* performance boost in micro-benchmarks, but with no evidence that the boost is significant in your app - or a simple `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Pattern>` which is hard to get wrong, and will almost certainly be good enough? This is a micro-optimization: don't do it until you've proved you need to.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'll test both in the real app. The method is part of a program that uses up 100% of all CPU cores all year long, on many machines. I know what they say about premature optimization, but I think I really could use the 1% performance boost.

Comment: @AndrewBourgeois: I *very* much doubt you'll get a 1% performance boost just by caching Matchers instead of Patterns, unless you spend most of your time matching regular expressions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there are no matchers for a regexp, you create a new matcher, but you also add it to the queue right away:

```
if (matcher == null) {
    // No matchers available, create one
    // No lock needed, as it's not a drama to have a few more matchers in the queue
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    matcherQueue.offer(matcher); // Don't add it to the queue here!
}
```

Thus it will be in the queue while you are using it, and another thread could easily get a hold of it before you are done.

I don't know if I agree with your idea of pooling matchers by the way. They are not very expensive to create in terms of CPU cycles. You probably want to profile it to see if it's worth it. Precompiling the `Pattern` is a good idea, however.

Comment: That is indeed not a very smart thing to do, thank you! Jon Skeet had the same thought about the Matcher, I think I should test it with a few GB of text and real regexs.

Comment: Yep, test it! It's the only way to know if your getMatcher() will be faster than instantiating a new one. Oh, and if it is a long-running job you want to make sure you are using Java with the `-server` flag as it is more aggressive about inlining. This can even reduce the amount of memory that ends up being allocated for a new matcher.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Matcher, you offer it to the Queue before returning it, so the next thread gets it right away.

```
matcher = pattern.matcher(value);  
matcherQueue.offer(matcher);        // <-- this line should be taken taken out and shot

...

return matcher;
```

Also, your duplicateHunter HashSet is not thread safe and may give you the wrong results when validating against it.